# React onClick not working to start a timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there have been a few of these questions posted but I haven't been able to find an answer to work. My code is below. Everything links, and I was able to get a more simple timer working that just starts timing when the component mounts, but now I want to make it more interactive. however, when I click the button nothing happens. What I am trying to do is have a component that is a button, when clicked it becomes a timer and displays the amount of time passed since clicked. But clicking the button doesn't do any thing.

thanks for the help!

```
var StartButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
    return { elapsed: 0, go: false };
  },
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      interval: 1000
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    console.log('mounted');
  },
  tick: function(){
    console.log('tick')
    this.setState({elapsed: new Date() - this.state.start});
  },
  startCount: function(e){
    console.log(e);
    console.log('GO!!!')  
    this.state.props = Date.now;
    this.state.go = true;  
    this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, this.props.interval);
  },
  render: function(){
    var self = this;
    var elapsed = Math.round(this.state.elapsed / 100);
    var seconds = (elapsed / 10).toFixed(3); 
    var clickMe = <button onCLick={self.startCount} >GO</button>;
    var display = <div>time elapsed {this.state.elapsed}</div>
    return (
        <div>
          {this.state.go ? display : clickMe}
        </div>
      )    
  }
})

var AppContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (<div><StartButton interval={1000} /></div>);
  }
})

$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('in ready');
  ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer></AppContainer>, document.getElementById('jake'));
});
```

Comment: This likely isn't the entirety of your problem, but you  are setting elements of the state directly, which can cause issues with how React works.  Start by replacing any instance of `this.state.____ = ____` with `this.setState` calls.

Comment: thanks @gravityplanx, I changed the bit of startCount to
    this.setState({state: Date.now, go: true}); 
but the console logs arent being hit to the call back is never being called

Comment: Just to solidify what @gravityplanx said, React's data structure is immutable, each time you want to update a components state you actually replace the current state with the new one (via `this.setState`) if you perform updates the way you are doing, you can mutate the internal consistency of your component state causing unexpected behaviour (also this.state.x will not force an update of your component, this.setState will refresh the component with the new state).  Remember to use `this.setState` for writes and ONLY ever use `this.state.property` for reads.

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typo in your question but you have the button onClick spelt as onCLick, which won't work.

Comment: wow silliest errors are the hardest to find... thank you @BenHare

Comment: If you looked in the console, it should actually of said `onCLick is not a function` :P

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found all the small errors by now, but in case you haven't, here's a working copy of your component;

```
var StartButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return { elapsed: 0, go: false };
    },
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            interval: 1000
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        console.log('mounted');
    },
    tick: function(){
        console.log('tick')
        this.setState({elapsed: Date.now() - this.state.start});
    },
    startCount: function(e){
        console.log(e);
        console.log('GO!!!')
        this.setState({start: Date.now(), go: true})
        setInterval(this.tick, this.props.interval);
    },
    render: function(){
        var clickMe = <button onClick={this.startCount} >GO</button>;
        var display = <div>time elapsed {Math.round(this.state.elapsed / 1000)} seconds</div>
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.go ? display : clickMe}
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is here with `onClick`:

```
var clickMe = <button onClick={self.startCount} >GO</button>;
```

Comment: Way to just copy the answer I provided in the comments.